# simple way to remotely trigger my pc

Tags: windows, networking, python, remote

I have a python script which updates data on my google sheets which I access through my phone alot.

I'm trying to enable me to trigger that script remotely, even if I'm not at home (outside LAN).

Now, I know that for that, I need to run a server, fix my ip address and listen to requests, and exposing ports.

doing such, is risky and too complicated for my purpose.

running a LAN based server is simple as this code:

```
from bottle import Bottle, request

app = Bottle()

@app.get('/')
def home():
    return "hello"

@app.route('/<key>')
def main(key):
    if key == '123':
        # here I will call my script
        return "executing script..."
    else:
        return key

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

that way if I put the correct key it will execute my file..

As you can tell, my security here (and basicly my skills) are pretty low so I don't rush to expose my ports outside my router and fix my ip.

are there any prebuilt solutions to perform that task?

Comment: Have you considered running [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki) on the PC and using an SSH client on your phone _(if Android, [JuiceSSH](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonelli.juicessh&hl=en_US) is a great option)_?  If your ISP does not assign you a static WAN IP, any remote access to your LAN from WAN will require a [DDNS](https://dyn.com/dynamic-dns/) address and DDNS client running [preferably] on a router or on the PC.

Comment: @Yarden .... Another option to NOT expose any ports from the untrusted outside world through your router to a service would be to have a process on the internal server check the "content" of an externally readable file [FTP], site [html page], etc. which you control the content of `ON` or `OFF` and can update\change it as needed for the server to then do something when the content is `ON`. When you want to trigger, update it to `ON`. Have the server logic change it back to `OFF` after each `ON` this way you just set `ON` as needed to ensure `1` execution.

Comment: This way the only thing you expose is the view of some value. You can put it on SSH FTP, ftps, etc. for security as well if needed. The server job would be automated to check this and when it sense a change or the value equals something, then have it take action accordingly. The logic and task scheduler, etc. automation is just trivial regarding the matter regardless. I'd pure PowerShell script the entire server process or perhaps use Python if you know how.

Comment: Alternatively, set up Dropbox (other Cloud services are available) and have a permanently running script that checks for the presence of a file that gets synced to your machine. Upon running your script you delete or rename the file, and to run it again you simply rename the file back again. The file could simply be a zero-byte "run-my-thing.txt" file. No internet port open, no need to program a http watcher, just look for a particular file appearing. You can also combine it with Pimps ON/OFF logic.

Comment: Neat idea! @mokubai